# Text format not supported in UITextView

Tags: ios

I am getting a text information in this format after firing a URL and I am not being able to print that in a `UITextView`.
It's showing me error like : "`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`"

The result I am getting after `JSON` Parsing is a text in this format:

"desc1":"New Delhi: The Indian Grand Prix, which was dropped from the Formula One calendar after three successful seasons between 2011 and 2013, could be back on track in 2016, the race promoters said.\r\n\r\n“We had been desperately trying to get the Grand Prix back at the Buddh International Circuit (BIC) ever since it was dropped from the calendar,” said a senior official of the Jaypee Sports International (JPSI) on Wednesday.\r\n\r\n“Recently, our top boss, Sameer Gaur, had a meeting with the F1 supremo Bernie Ecclestone in Sochi on bringing the race back to India. They had a fruitful discussion, and if everything goes accordingly, then the Indian GP should vroom once again in 2016,” he said.\r\n\r\nThe Indian leg was dropped rather abruptly after the 2013 race despite the fact that Formula One Management (FOM) had a five-year contract with the promoters.\r\n",

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this code:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSString *message=[dict objectForKey:@"desc1"];
self.textView.text=message
```

**Note:** returnData is the data getting from web service that is responseData (it is of type NSData).

**OR**

```
NSString * description=[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"desc1"];
self.textView.text= description;
```